# MVC Simple Membership - How to change login URL when unauthorized?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I have an MVC project that I am using simple membership with, and i have some actions marked with `[Authorize]`.

When a user who is not logged in tries to view one of these actions, they are redirected to /Account/Login. How do I change that URL? I need it to go to /Account/Account/Login.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe Jasens answer is correct when using regular membership with ASP.NET, However I've discovered that with SimpleMembership it does not work.

To change it with SimpleMembership, the following record needs to be added in the web.config under `<appSettings>`

```
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/Your/Login/Url"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Specify the URL in **web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```